# Find file ending with .sh OR .bin

Tags: bash, unix, find

How can I find all the files ending with .sh OR .bin in a given folder.

I know I can do:

```
find /path/to/folder -name "*.bin"
```

to find all bin file. What must I add to also look for .sh files ?

Comment: Assuming you also want files and not directories, you should add `-type f` or `! -type d`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The manual page tells you that `-o` is the OR operator. If you want case insensitivity, use `iname` instead of `name`.

```
find /path/to/folder -iname "*.bin" -o -iname "*.sh"
```

Comment: Are '.SH' and '.sH' and '.Sh' files the same as '.sh' files?

Comment: Also, note that on some systems (Solaris 10, for example) you need to use `find /path/to/folder -name '*.bin' -print -o -name '*.sh' -print` with two explicit print options.

Comment: you're right, in UNIX systems, script shells usually have a lower case extension. This is however not a rule that I know of.

Comment: @Jonathan: wouldn't most accept `find /path/to/folder \( -name '*.bin' -o -name '*.sh' \) -print`?

Comment: @Hasturkun : Probably, but you must take care of escaping the parentheses so that you shell does not interpret them. So, `find /path \( -name '*.bin' -o -name '*.sh' \) -print` (assuming bash). Using a find port under Windows with cmd, no need to escape those parens, nor stars.

Comment: @Benoit: I actually did escape them... it looks like SO turns `\\(` to `\(` (maybe I should complain about this on meta...)

Comment: @Hasturkan: most versions of `find` would accept your invocation with '`\\(`' and '`\\)`' as already discussed and explained (and SO markup has definitely been changed again).  POSIX requires the 'default print' clause - but I checked on Solaris 10 that the version you stated does not work as written.  I've been bitten by that before.